# Filter list of objects by properties and generate list of properties in java

Tags: java, list, filter

Say I have an object

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class Foo {
 String name;
 int age;
}

public static void main() {
  List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
  ... populate list...
  List<String> filteredByName = getFilteredList(fooList);
}

public List<String> getFilteredList(List<Foo> fooList) {
  List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(Foo foo : fooList) {
     if("someword".isGreaterThan(foo.getName()) {
        nameList.add(foo.getName());
     }
  }
}
```

I'd like to have a one line representation of getFilteredList. 
Google Guava/ Apache have Predicates, that can filter a list of objects to a smaller list, not sure if there is something similar to filter out a list of properties alone.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Java 8, use streams to filter your list:

```
public List<String> getFilteredList(List<Foo> fooList) {
    return fooList.stream().filter(f -> "someword".compareTo(f.getName()) > 0))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```